# Selection.Count overflow when selecting all cells

Tags: vba, excel, overflow

In Excel 2007 I want to prompt a message when a cell (L2) is clicked on. I have a piece of code that works but the problem is that when I select all the cells in the sheet with `Ctrl+A` I get error number `06: overflow` on the line `If Selection.Count = 1 Then`

Mandatory VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "ACTION!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        If InStr(1, CStr(Target.Address), ":") < 1 Then
            If Selection.Count = 1 Then
                If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2")) Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "ACTION!"
                End If
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why this additional `If`-guard fixes the problem? Are there any other known boundary conditions? If yes then where are they documented? Should not the guard look like `Not Selection Is Nothing`?

Answer (score 11):

Easily fixed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "ACTION!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the difference between Selection.CountLarge and Selection.Count?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. [CountLarge is the 64-bit equivalent of Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge) and so does not experience overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your code as follows. No Error-Traps needed:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Area.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "ACTION!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you had 64-bit Excel I would tell you to use `CountLarge` instead of `Count`.  Excel 2007 only comes in the 32-bit variety so that's not an option for you.

Your problem is that `Range.Count` returns a `Long` variable and throws an error if the number of cells is greater than a `Long` can store.

To get around this, you can do the following:

1. Use a `Decimal` data type stored inside a `Variant`.  The combination can count more than the 1,048,576 rows x 16,384 columns of cells in an Excel worksheet.
2. Count the cells one column at a time to avoid the error with `Range.Count`.

I wrote a function that does that.  Save this function in a regular code module (not a Worksheet or Workbook module) and use it like this:

```
If CountLarge32(Selection) = 1 Then
```

Here's the actual function:

```
Public Function CountLarge32(ByVal rangeOrSelection As Variant) As Variant

    Dim target As Excel.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set target = rangeOrSelection
    On Error GoTo 0


    Dim cnt As Variant
    Dim iColumn As Excel.Range

    If Not target Is Nothing Then                   ' parameter -IS- a valid Range

        ' Use Range.Count on one column at a time to avoid the overflow error
        '   if counting higher than the limit of the Long data type.
        For Each iColumn In target.Columns
            cnt = CDec(cnt + iColumn.Cells.Count)
        Next iColumn

        CountLarge32 = cnt

    End If
End Function
```

This function also avoids the error that occurs if Select is an object (e.g. button, shape, chart, etc.) instead of a cell.